# C++ unordered_map::insert won't compile

Tags: c++, constants, mutable

I just need a hash map from one float to another.  Should be simple, shouldn't it?  Compiler just won't accept it:

**Declaration:**

```
unordered_map<float, float> m_mffPhotoPeakMap;
```

**Use:**

```
float CProductSpecs::AddToMap(float fEnergy, float returnedValue) const
{
    auto pair = make_pair(fEnergy, returnedValue);
    m_mffPhotoPeakMap.insert(pair);                 // Error!  (First attempt)
    m_mffPhotoPeakMap[fEnergy] = returnedValue;     // Error!  (Second attempt)
    return returnedValue;
}
```

**Error message (first attempt):**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2663   'std::_Hash<std::_Umap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,std::_Uhash_compare<_Kty,_Hasher,_Keyeq>,_Alloc,false>>::insert': 6 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
```

**Error message (second attempt):**

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2678   binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::unordered_map<float,float,std::hash<float>,std::equal_to<_Kty>,std::allocator<std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

The error messages don't make sense to me -- the syntax appears correct.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It's that `const`. You promised you wouldn't mutate the object, and you're trying to mutate the object. The compile is trying to prevent you from breaking your promise.

Comment: `insert` obviously would modify the map, so you cannot do that in the `const` method (unless that member is mutable)

Comment: Don't add `[SOLVED]` to the question title, and don't add a solution to the question. Instead, *accept* an answer that helped you the most by clicking the green tick to the left of it. (You can write your own if you think none of them are worthy.) It's the intended way to indicate that your problem is solved.

Comment: 1) "_The solution was <...>_" The problem you were experiencing, was not described in the question, in the form of [mre], hence it isn't clear how that was a solution to your problem. 2) You can answer your question yourself. You shouldn't put answers in the questions.

Comment: Also, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328379/why-are-fellow-users-removing-thank-yous-from-my-questions?noredirect=1

Answer (score 8):

You are in a `const` member function trying to mutate a member variable.

Make CProductSpecs::AddToMap not be `const`.

Comment: Thanks jwezorek.  AddToMap needs to be constant because it's returned from a const method, which is invoked from a const object.  Any idea how to modify an object in a const method?

Comment: const_cast ... but don't. Re-design your code to be const correct or just drop all the consts everywhere.

Comment: @UserX It doesn't make sense for `AddToMap()` to be `const`. Sounds like your code has wider const correctness issues.

Comment: @UserX "_AddToMap needs to be constant because it's returned from a const method_" What does that even mean? I can imagine several possibilities, none of them preventing you to drop the `const`. Please provide [mre], since, currently, it seems like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks again.  There are many consts int the code and they're correct.  I just need one exception, but I don't see how const_cast can be used here.  It can't be used on the unordered_map, and the containing class doesn't appear in the method.  How can const_cast avoid this problem?

Comment: @UserX Technically, `const_cast` could help you avoid compilation error, but could, potentially, cause undefined behavior in your code instead, hence the "don't" part.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius : AddToMap() is returned by a const method.  If I remove const from AddToMap(), every place it's called gets the error: "cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const CProductSpecs' to  'CProductSpecs &'.

Comment: Something is returning the member function?

Comment: @jwezorek: Yes.  A const method invokes AddToMap() in its return statement.

Comment: @UserX Code is more understandable, than descriptions of code. Descriptions can be interpreted in multitude of different ways: code can't be. If you want solution to your actual problem, rather than perceived problem, please provide [mre] in the question.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius: Thanks for the suggestion, but in this case it seemed like everyone who saw the method understood what the problem was.

Comment: @UserX But your descriptions of "I can't remove the `const`" pointed at this being [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and this not being an actual problem, you were trying to solve.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius: Yes, it does appear to be an XY problem.  But the answers I got made me realize the solution wouldn't work, and led me to coming up with a solution that did work.

Comment: @UserX Sure, I am just saying, that if you provided [mre], we would've helped you solve your real problem, whatever it was.

Answer (score 3):

The function is declared as a constant non-static member function,

```
float CProductSpecs::AddToMap(float fEnergy, float returnedValue) const
                                                                  ^^^^^
```

So you may not use the function to change data members of the constant object. You could do that only in the case when the data member `m_mffPhotoPeakMap` is declared with the storage class specifier `mutable`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put AddToMap() and the map into a separate class, which can be called from const methods.

Comment: That seems like a solution to work around bad design. Perhaps you should take a few steps back and rethink what you're doing, about your requirement, and why you marked the function as `const` to begin with.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It's a optimization in a vast, const-correct class.  I don't think the design is bad: 1. The class is still const-correct, 2. The cache is self-contained in its own class, and 3. Caching values to avoid recalculation sped up the overall operation by over 10%, which is significant.

Answer (score 0):

I found a better solution: Declare the map as "mutable", making it an exception to the const attribute:

```
mutable unordered_map<float, float> m_mffPhotoPeakMap;
```